# Inserting data into database using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently having some troubles inserting data into my database. Everything I put in some data in my site it gives the error: 'Database Insert 1 Failed'. Moreover, when I remove the first query from the code I get the next error: 'Database Insert 2 Failed'. And so on...

What am I doing wrong? Are their any flaws in my code?

Description of my database:

- 6 tables: user, naam, woon, sexe, jaar and hobby
- Each table has 'Lidnummer', which is set to A-I, primary key and Unique Value. It is a INTEGER with max-length 255
- Ingelogd is a BOOLEAN.
- Dag, maand and jaar are also integer with max-length 255
- Email has an Unique Value and is a char with max-length 255
- Rest of the variables are chars with max-length 255

How can I fix this? Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,

Ps. Code Below for those, who didn't notice ;) Also, if somebody needs some extra information, of course feel free to ask. I will provide it as well as possible.

Connect.php:

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'datingsite');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Register.php:

```
<?php
    Include('connect.php');


    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['wachtwoord'])){

        $lidnummer = NULL;
        $email = $_POST['email'];       
        $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
        $Ingelogd = 0;

        $Voornaam = $_POST['Voornaam'];
        $Tweedenaam = $_POST['Tweedenaam'];
        $Achternaam = $_POST['Achternaam'];     

        $Woonplaats = $_POST['Woonplaats'];
        $Provincie = $_POST['Provincie'];

        $Ben = $_POST['Ben'];
        $Zoek = $_POST['Zoek']; 


        $Dag = $_POST['Dag'];
        $Maand = $_POST['Maand'];
        $Jaar = $_POST['Jaar'];

        $Hobby1 = $_POST['Hobby1'];
        $Hobby2 = $_POST['Hobby2'];
        $Opleiding = $_POST['Opleiding'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO 'user' (Lidnummer, Email, Wachtwoord, Ingelogd) 
        VALUES (
            '$lidnummer',
            '$email', 
            '$wachtwoord', 
            '$Ingelogd')";

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO  'naam' (Lidnummer, Voornaam, Tweedenaam, Achternaam)
        VALUES (            
            '$lidnummer',
            '$Voornaam', 
            '$Tweedenaam', 
            '$Achternaam')";

        $query3 = "INSERT INTO  'woon' (Lidnummer, Woonplaats, Provincie)
        VALUES (
            '$lidnummer',
            '$Woonplaats', 
            '$Provincie')";

        $query4 = "INSERT INTO  'sexe' (Lidnummer, Ben, Zoek)
        VALUES (                
            '$lidnummer',
            '$Ben', 
            '$Zoek')";

        $query5 = "INSERT INTO  'jaar' (Lidnummer, Dag, Maand, Jaar)
        VALUES (                
            '$lidnummer',
            '$Dag', 
            '$Maand', 
            '$Jaar')";
        $query6 = "INSERT INTO  'hobby' (Lidnummer, Hobby1, Hobby2, Opleiding)
        VALUES (                
            '$lidnummer',
            '$Hobby1', 
            '$Hobby2', 
            '$Opleiding')";


        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (!$res){
        die("Database Insert 1 Failed" . mysql_error());}

        $res2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        if (!$res2){
        die("Database Insert 2 Failed" . mysql_error());}

        $res3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
        if (!$res3){
        die("Database Insert 3 Failed" . mysql_error());}

        $res4 = mysqli_query($connection, $query4);
        if (!$res4){
        die("Database Insert 4 Failed" . mysql_error());}

        $res5 = mysqli_query($connection, $query5);
        if (!$res5){
        die("Database Insert 5 Failed" . mysql_error());}

        $res6 = mysqli_query($connection, $query6);
        if (!$res6){
        die("Database Insert 6 Failed" . mysql_error());}

        if(($res)&&($res2)&&($res3)&&($res4)&&($res5)&&($res6)){
            $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }
    }
    ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Registreren op Chives</title>
<link href="../Css/inlog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="../Css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />






</head>

<body class="back">
<?php
    if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
 ?> 
<div id="Inlog-Container" align="center">
<form action="" method="post">


    <H1> Registreren </H1>
    <H2> Email:</H2>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="Input-box" required/>
    <H2> Wachtwoord:</H2>
    <input name="wachtwoord" type="password" class="Input-box"  required/>
<div class="Radiolabelbox">
    <fieldset class="" id="" >

                  <H2>Ik ben een:</H2>

                  <div class="Radiolabel">  
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="Ben" class="styled-radio" value="Man" required/>
                        Man
                    </label> <br />

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Ben" class="styled-radio" value="Vrouw"/>
                        Vrouw                
                    </label>
                   </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="">

                  <H2 class="">Ik zoek een:</H2>

                  <div class="Radiolabel">
                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Zoek" class="styled-radio" value="Man" required/>
                        Man
                    </label> 
                    <br />

                      <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Zoek" class="styled-radio" value="Vrouw"/>
                        Vrouw   
                    </label> 
                      <br />

                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="Zoek" class="styled-radio" value="Beide"/>
                        Beide
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
      </div>
    <H2> Woonplaats:</H2>
    <input name="Woonplaats" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Provincie:</H2>
    <input name="Provincie" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Hobby 1:</H2>
    <input name="Hobby1" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Hobby 2:</H2>
    <input name="Hobby2" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Voornaam:</H2>
    <input name="Voornaam" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Tweede naam:</H2>
    <input name="Tweedenaam" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Achternaam:</H2>
    <input name="Achternaam" type="text" class="Input-box"  required/>
    <H2> Geboortedag:</H2>
    <input name="Dag" type="Number" class="Input-box" min="0" max="31" required/>
    <H2> Geboortemaand:</H2>
    <input name="Maand" type="Number" class="Input-box" min="0" max="12" required/>
    <H2> Geboortejaar:</H2>
    <input name="Jaar" type="Number" class="Input-box" min="1920" max="2000" required/>
    <H2> Opleiding:</H2>
    <input name="Opleiding" type="Text" class="Input-box"  required/>    

    <input type="submit" value="GA VERDER" class="Roundbutton" id="Login" />
</form>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, you're mixing APIs with `mysql_error()` - Use `mysqli_error($connection)` for all of them.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong identifiers for all your tables. Read up on the subject http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html - `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()` would have told you that. So remove the quotes from around the table names, or use ticks `\``

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. I will change this immediately @Fred-ii-

Comment: So, I have changed the mysql_error() into mysqli_error() and now I get this error: -------------------------------------------- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' (Lidnummer, Email, Wachtwoord, Ingelogd) VALUES ( '', 'frontname'      ------------------------------------------------  frontname is part of an email adress called 'frontname.backname@my-email.com'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're mixing APIs with `mysql_error()` - Use `mysqli_error($connection)` for all of them.

Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

Then you're using the wrong identifiers for **all** your table names, being quotes.

Read up on the subject http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Adding `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()` would have signaled that.

- Remove the quotes from around the table names, or use ticks.

(if spaces are present, or hyphens, or a reserved keyword, then the ticks are required)

I.e.:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `user`
```

or remove them

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO user
```

- Follow the same method for all the table names in all your queries.

---

I must also note that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: You fixed my problem! That's exactly what I needed! Thanks tons of times!!